# Having debugger open Firefox in current tab instead of creating new tab

Tags: debugging, firefox

So every time I run a debug from my development IDE and Firefox is called to display my app, I get my app displayed in a new Firefox tab. That means one new tab every time I start a debug session and before long I've got 10-20 Firefox tabs open.

Can I have it so it reuses the existing tab open?

I could only find Firefox command line options to open new windows etc, not to use the current window/tab.

Comment: You can check the following link [force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/)

Answer (score -1):

Just in case the above link disappears, it details going to the about:config screen in Firefox (just enter **about:config** in address bar) and changing the value of 'browser.link.open_newwindow' from 3 to 1.